# ROS Answers SE migration: hector repo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i can't figure out what kind of repo is hector ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42224/hector-repo/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-24**:
of sorry if may i clear my question it's  a simulator ? can i use it on asctec pelican

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-24**:
of sorry if may i clear my question it's  a simulator ? can i use it on asctec pelican

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-08-26**:
There is a simulated quadrotor available in the hector_quadrotor stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/) is a svn-based repo. We currently haven't yet generated Debian packages for our stacks, so you'll have to manually do either

```
svn checkout http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg-read-only
```

for checking out the electric version of the packages

or

```
svn checkout http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fuerte/ tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg-read-only
```

for the fuerte version of the packages.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0